# Problemas al crear menú dinámico

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

Estoy intentado usar `MetisMenu` con `Vue.js`, todo va bien, pero al momento de crear estos menus dinámicos con axios dejan de funcionar, estoy llamando inclusive a la función que activa dicho menu.

```
<div class="sidebar-collapse">
  <ul class="nav metismenu" id="side-menu">
    <li v-for="data of datas" :key="data">
       <a href="#" aria-expanded="false" class="clicked">
          <i class="fa fa-th-large"></i> 
          <span class="nav-label">Menus dinámicos</span> 
          <span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
          <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
            <li><a href="index.html">Sub menu 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="dashboard_2.html">Sub menu 2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

En otro archivo main.js llamo Metis.

```
$('#side-menu').metisMenu(); // Funciona si los menús son estáticos
```

El problema es cuando genero los menús dinámicos:

```
mounted() {
    // $("#side-menu").metisMenu();
    this.load();
  },
  methods: {
    load() {
      let me = this;
      setTimeout(function() {
        me.datas = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
        // Espera que todos los elementos se hayan cargado en el DOM
        Vue.nextTick(
          function() {
            $("#side-menu").metisMenu();
            $(".clicked").on("click", function() {
              console.log("Hola");
            });
          }.bind(this)
        );
      }, 1000);
    },
  }
```

Con `nextTick` espero que termine de procesar, puse `setTime` par simular una petición ajax. El jquery funciona correctamente, hice la prueba usando click.

la función de extender y contraer el menú deja de funcionar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Marcial, ¿podrías crear un [mcve] en la propia pregunta para que podamos ver el problema? Tal y como está ahora no sé si hay suficiente información para saber qué es lo que falla.

Comment: El problema son tus settimeouts, y si cuando ejecuta no ha cargado el dom es porque tus javascript están importados en la posición incorrecta

Comment: No entiendo porque usar jquery si estas usando vue y en los ejemplos de codigo que aportaste no se puede verificar que estas haciendo mal. Podrias crear un ejemplo en stackblitz.com o jsfiddle.net y utilizar fakejson.com para emular una api rest en el backend con eso podemos ver el flujo completo de tu codigo y detectar el error. Saludos.

Comment: @DiegoAlbertoZapataHäntsch usa jQuery para poder usar MetisMenu ( un plugin de jQuery )

Comment: @abrahamhs mepa que no es el timeout sino la des-sincronización entre el DOM que ve vue y el DOM que ve jQuery/MetisMenu, vue es muy celoso de que no le toquen las cosas, habría que ver la manera de que se lleven bien ( creando un componente por ejemplo ),  o reescribir la funcionalidad de MetisMenu en vue prescindiendo de jQuery

Comment: Estimados, puse setTime para simular la carga axios, ya que tiene un retraso, y sí, intenté llevarlo a componentes pero no tuve exito! Saludos

Comment: @alo Malbarez  ¿Por que crees que se desincroniza?? Los códigos no se estan ejecutando sincronizadamente ¿Y cual crees que sea una de las razones? Ahh! hay un código que se ejecuta hasta 1 segundo después.

Comment: No entiendo tu comentario.

Comment: @abrahamhs se des-sincroniza por que vue mantiene un DOM "virtual" es la forma que tiene de mantener la coherencia de estados y datos con two way binding. sea un segundo o 3 despues si vue quien controla el DOM real no se entera del cambio que hizo jQuery... pues lo va a reemplazar con lo que vue "ve"

Comment: una idea: [`v-once`](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-once) para que el componente renderice el html del menú ( y quede estático ) luego emite un evento para que la app aplique el metisMenu ( si lo podes instanciar en el global podrías usar [`dispose`](https://mm.onokumus.com/mm-dispose.html) para ver que retome el nuevo html )

Comment: @aloMalbarez si eso lo se pero se puede usar MetisMenu sin jQuery(https://github.com/onokumus/metismenujs)